# xml for custom MS Access ribbon with multiple tabs

Tags: xml, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-office, ribbonx

I'm trying to create a ribbon with multiple tabs for an app
This is the code I have and it's not working, no errors (except that VBA opens on startup, I'm assuming something IS happening behind the scenes that it's not liking), but the toolbar isn't there, I get the regular Access toolbar

This is a test toolbar, so I'm repeating buttons, etc. I wrote a little app in access that stamps the XML based on choices made in the app and I was testing it out. The app works fine for toolbars with 1 tab but for multiple tabs - no luck

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<customUI
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="OnLoadRibbon" loadImage="OnLoadImage">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="true">
        <tabs>
            <tab id="tabMain" label="Kroka">
                <group id="grpAppOptions" label="App Options">
                    <button id="btnLock" label="Lock Database" onAction="macLock" getImage="FGetRibbonImages" size="large"/>
                    <button id="btnPublishFile" label="Publish File" onAction="macPublishFile" getImage="FGetRibbonImages" size="large"/>
                    <button id="btnAdmin" label="Admin Settings" onAction="macAdmin" getImage="FGetRibbonImages" size="large"/>
                    <button id="btnExit" label="Exit App" onAction="macExit" getImage="FGetRibbonImages" size="large"/>
                </group>
                <group id="grpReports" label="Reports">
                    <button id="btnCloseReport" label="Close Report" onAction="macCloseReport" getImage="FGetRibbonImages" size="large"/>
                    <button id="btnExit" label="Exit App" onAction="macExit" getImage="FGetRibbonImages" size="large"/>
                </group>
            </tab>
            <tab id="tabTest" label="Kroka2">
                <group id="grpAppOptions" label="App Options">
                    <button id="btnSubmitIdea" label="Submit Idea" onAction="macCustomers" getImage="FGetRibbonImages" size="large"/>
                    <button id="btnPublishFile" label="Publish File" onAction="macPublishFile" getImage="FGetRibbonImages" size="large"/>
                    <button id="btnCustomers" label="Customers" onAction="macCustomers" getImage="FGetRibbonImages" size="large"/>
                    <button id="btnExit" label="Exit App" onAction="macExit" getImage="FGetRibbonImages" size="large"/>
                </group>
                <group id="grpReports" label="Reports">
                    <button id="btnCloseReport" label="Close Report" onAction="macCloseReport" getImage="FGetRibbonImages" size="large"/>
                    <button id="btnExit" label="Exit App" onAction="macExit" getImage="FGetRibbonImages" size="large"/>
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs should be unique. But they are duplicated on both tabs in your ribbon XML markup.

By default, if an add-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom ribbon does not appear, or why a ribbon appears but no controls appear. Read more about that in the [How to: Show Add-in user interface errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-show-add-in-user-interface-errors?view=vs-2022) article.

Comment: Thank you! Pretty sure I tried renaming the group ids, this is just one of the versions, I tried so many  but it's good to know they should be unique for the future. But turning on errors is really useful, will try today and write back

Comment: Huge thank you! This helped. Turns out that you also can't have the same buttons repeat on any ribbons. Can you please add that to your answer and I will accept?

Comment: I've already mentioned that you can't have IDs duplicated in the ribbon XML. Isn't the same?

Comment: I guess you're right, for some reason it didn't hit me that it applies to buttons  maybe others are smarter. In any case, thank you, I was at this for 2 days